# When an extension is invoked, what runs first?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When an extension is invoked or started, what is the first thing that is run? Is there some default .js file that is loaded first? Is there something comparable to main() in the C world? It's not clear from the tutorial or other doc what you have to write, what to call it, and where to put it so that it's the first thing that gets executed when an extension is launched/opened.

Thanks,

Comment: If your extension has one, the background page: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html

Comment: Thanks, Rob W - between your comment and the one below, that answered my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rob-w points out the background.js would run first, if you have created one and correctly defined it in the manifest.

```
  "background": {
    "scripts" : ["background.js"]
  },
```

Then if you are running [content-scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html), you can specify in the manifest the point at which these scripts are executed, using the `run_at` directive. In most cases you'd set the script to run at the "document_end" so you can interact with the DOM. But you can also set it to run at "document_start" or "document_idle" ([see usage here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration)).

```
{
  "matches": ["*://www.whateverdomain.com/*"],
  "js": ["myscript.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
```

Comment: FYI your match pattern is invalid, domain names cannot have a wildcard. You need to add a `/` before the last asterisk, see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html.

Comment: That's odd, I seems I have one working in production like that. But I'll adjust inline with the documentation.

Comment: QF_Developer - thank you! That was the missing bit of info I needed, and works like a charm, so thanks again for enlightening. Now, one other question: My launch script creates a panel window with `chrome.windows.create`; with the window created, how do I insert HTML or script into it? It's not a tab or Chrome window, but a panel. Again, not clear from docs on how to achieve that. Thanks again!

Comment: No probs. I'm not sure about panels, but I suspect they behave in similar way to other windows. If the panel is holding a 3rd party site you should be able to target a content-script against it. As I say...not sure, you may want to pose this as a new question on StackOverflow.